# FFmpeg - Audio Tag | Galician

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, tags, iso

I need your help on FFmpeg and an audio track tag.

I'm generating a ProRes LT whose main language is Galician.

I know that FFmpeg is based on List of ISO 639-2 codes but after several attempts, nothing helps. I tried "glg", "gal", "gl", "glc" but the audio remains untagged.

For information, I made a test with MKVToolNix and it manages to tag the language.

Could you help me to find the right solution to do the same with FFmpeg?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Currently not possible with FFmpeg for MOV

The FFmpeg MOV muxer does not yet support the [Extended Language Tag Atom (`elng`)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap2/qtff2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH204-SW16). So you are limited to the legacy [Macintosh Language Codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap4/qtff4.html) which does not include Galician.

See:

- Bug report [#7905: ISO 639-2 Code "frm" Support](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7905)
- Abandoned patch [[FFmpeg-devel] avformat/isom: allow ISO 639 codes for mov](https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/patch/20200620001006.159305-1-yonglel@google.com/)

Comment: Clear and simple, thank you very much for your answer. Too bad then :/